# Why is aframe animation complete event firing multiple times

Tags: aframe, virtual-reality, webvr

Hello I am new to aframe and I am creating a component where when I click on a plane some animation occurs and color of plane change. It is a very simple learning application, but I see that animation__complete is fired multiple times 1st time for 1 time second time twice and so on I do not understand what an I doing wrong I have attached the log of the file here link to project is https://glitch.com/~amethyst-lamprey-mltmsu585o also this is my first time posting question on stack overflow

Console log output:

```
about to emit fadein

(index):43 fadeincompleted

(index):35 about to emit fadein

2(index):43 fadeincompleted

(index):35 about to emit fadein

3(index):43 fadeincompleted

(index):35 about to emit fadein

4(index):43 fadeincompleted

(index):35 about to emit fadein

5(index):43 fadeincompleted

(index):35 about to emit fadein

6(index):43 fadeincompleted
```

Console log image:

[image: console log image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a `jQuery` usage issue. Your code is adding new event listeners each time the user clicks resulting in animations triggered multiple times. Move the code below outside of the `click` handler so it runs only once per `animationcomplete__fadein` event.

```
$(loading_sky).on("animationcomplete__fadein",()=>{
   console.log("fadeincompleted");
   el.setAttribute("color","#"+(Math.floor(100000 + Math. random() * 900000) ).toString());
   $.each(scene,(i,e)=>{ e.emit("fadein"); });
   setTimeout(()=>{loading_sky.emit("loadfadeout")},1100)});
 });
```

[Corrected glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/mire-bactrosaurus-sk57vrcyb7?path=index.html:38:41)